# Outputting a random image from an array using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to output a random image from my array and then remove it from the array afterwards for a matching game. I'm new to programming in general and I've seen (what I'm sure are) easier ways of doing it but nothing I understand yet so I'm trying it this way. The problem is that I can't get an image to print out and I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated! thanks!

HTML

```
<script>
            printImage(); Sites.splice(r,1); 
</script>
```

JS

```
var imgArray = new Array(); 
imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'img0.jpg';
...
imgArray[23] = new Image();
imgArray[23].src = 'img23.jpg';

ImageRotation = imgArray.length;
FirstHalf = '<img src="img';
LastHalf = '.jpg" style="width:100px; height: 100px;">';

function printImage() {
var r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * ImageRotation);
document.write(FirstHalf + r + LastHalf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do what you are tried to achieve:

I've used `setInterval` to demonstrate.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9273zmbd/1/)

#### HTML:

```
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=one" />
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var imgs = ['http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=one', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=two', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=three', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=four', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=five', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=six', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=seven', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=eight', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=nine', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=ten'];

setInterval(function() {
    var im = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    im.src = imgs[Math.round(Math.random() * (imgs.length - 1))];
}, 1000);
```

Comment: i have no idea how to use this site. but its more broken than it was before. Do i just change my original post to what it looks like now?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of setting the image, based on @chipChocolate.py's answer, and addressing OP's requirement that each image is removed from the list. Instead of changing the first image in the HTML, it rewrites the inner HTML within a `<div>` container.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var imgs = ['http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=one', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=two', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=three', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=four', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=five', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=six', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=seven', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=eight', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=nine', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=ten'];
var pictures = imgs.length;
var picim =[];
for (var i=0; i<pictures; i++)
    picim [i] = i;
var num = 0;            // current index of picture number

function randpic() {
    if (pictures > 1) {
        pictures--;
        for (var i=num; i<pictures; i++)   // remove current picture index
            picim[i] = picim[i+1];
        num = Math.floor(Math.random() * pictures);
        var content = '<IMG src="' + imgs[picim [num]] + '" />';
        document.getElementById('randpic').innerHTML = content;
        }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="randpic" onClick="javascript:randpic()">
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/252799/fff.png&text=one" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```